# How do slide bootstrap 4 modal dialog to right when closing using css or js

Tags: javascript, css, animation, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal which i apply css animation to slide in from right when opening, and it works nice but i will like to slide it back to right when custom close button is clicked instead of just hiding without animation.

Please anyone have an idea of how i can do this, have searched online but all i see is how to apply animation on open.

```js
function customOpen(element){
  $(element).modal({
    backdrop: false,
    keyboard: false
  });
}
function customClose(element){
  $(element).modal('hide');
}
$(document).on("click", "#open", function() {
  var elem = $(this).attr("data-element");
  customOpen(elem);
});
$(document).on("click", "#close", function() {
  var elem = $(this).attr("data-element");
  customClose(elem);
});
```

```css
.modal.fade {
    transition: opacity .0s linear !important;
}
.modal.fade:not(.show).left .modal-dialog {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(-125%, 0, 0);
}
.modal.fade:not(.show).right .modal-dialog {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(125%, 0, 0);
 -ms-transform: translate3d(125%, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(125%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(125%, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal modal-full fade right" id="newPage">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close" data-element='#newPage'>Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class='btn btn-primary btn' id="open" data-element='#newPage'>Open Right</a>
```

Answer (score 11):

Just use a custom class `modal-right` and change the `transform` property of `modal-dialog` accordingly. Bootstrap apply from `top` by default.

```css
.modal.fade.modal-right .modal-dialog {
  transform: translate(125%, 0px);
}

.modal.show.modal-right .modal-dialog {
  transform: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade modal-right" id="newPage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newPage" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newPage">Open Right</a>
```